# Removing files and directories inside an directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, command, delete

In Unix,How to remove files and directories from the directory named as parent. The parent directory is placed inside grandparent directory.i need to remove only the files and directories inside parent directory and not the parent directory 
What is the command used here
Help is appreciated

Comment: Why not just move into the directory where you want to delete the files and just use `rm` or just `rm -rf /the/directory/*` to delete what you want?

Comment: @NasirRiley  rm can be used to delete an complete directory and files without deleting itself???

Comment: @NasirRiley  what about rmdir?

Comment: Ibug answer worked

Comment: Yes, it can. `rmdir` only works if the directory is empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: Make sure to verify the glob results with `echo` before proceeding with `rm -rf`.

To delete all files within a directory (but not the directory itself):

```bsh
rm -rf path/to/dir/*
```

In case there are "hidden files" (files whose names start with a dot), Bash's `dotglob` option will help:

```bsh
# Run with Bash
shopt -s dotglob
rm -rf path/to/dir/*
```

Comment: /* - deleting what is inside and not the directory itself ,right???

Comment: rf is recursive force delete ?? Right??

Comment: @Arun Both correct.